# Streaming MutationGroups into Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to stream MutationGroups into spanner with SpannerIO.
The goal is to write new MuationGroups every 10 seconds, as we will use spanner to query near-time KPI's.

When I don't use any windows, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey cannot be applied to non-bounded PCollection in the GlobalWindow without a trigger. Use a Window.into or Window.triggering transform prior to GroupByKey.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.applicableTo(GroupByKey.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:204)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:120)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:472)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:286)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine$PerKey.expand(Combine.java:1585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine$PerKey.expand(Combine.java:1470)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:299)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$WriteGrouped.expand(SpannerIO.java:868)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$WriteGrouped.expand(SpannerIO.java:823)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:472)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:286)
    at quantum.base.transform.entity.spanner.SpannerProtoWrite.expand(SpannerProtoWrite.java:52)
    at quantum.base.transform.entity.spanner.SpannerProtoWrite.expand(SpannerProtoWrite.java:20)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:299)
    at quantum.entitybuilder.pipeline.EntityBuilderPipeline$Write$SpannerWrite.expand(EntityBuilderPipeline.java:388)
    at quantum.entitybuilder.pipeline.EntityBuilderPipeline$Write$SpannerWrite.expand(EntityBuilderPipeline.java:372)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:491)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:299)
    at quantum.entitybuilder.pipeline.EntityBuilderPipeline.main(EntityBuilderPipeline.java:122)
:entityBuilder FAILED
```

Because of the error above I assume the input collection needs to be windowed and triggered, as SpannerIO uses a GroupByKey (this is also what I need for my use case):

```
        ...
        .apply("1-minute windows", Window.<MutationGroup>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
            ).orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
            .discardingFiredPanes()
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO))
        .apply(SpannerIO.write()
                    .withProjectId(entityConfig.getSpannerProject())
                    .withInstanceId(entityConfig.getSpannerInstance())
                    .withDatabaseId(entityConfig.getSpannerDb())
                    .grouped());
```

When I do this, I get the following exceptions during runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to get side input window for GlobalWindow from non-global WindowFn
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.PartitioningWindowFn$1.getSideInputWindow(PartitioningWindowFn.java:49)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:631)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$UserStepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:683)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.storeIfBlocked(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:182)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:71)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:323)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:271)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:219)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:69)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:517)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:505)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.values.ValueWithRecordId$StripIdsDoFn.processElement(ValueWithRecordId.java:145)
```

After investigating further it appears to be due to the `.apply(Wait.on(input))` in SpannerIO: It has a global side input which does not seem to work with my fixed windows, as the docs of `Wait.java` state:

```
If signal is globally windowed, main input must also be. This typically would be useful
 *       only in a batch pipeline, because the global window of an infinite PCollection never
 *       closes, so the wait signal will never be ready.
```

As a temporary workaround I tried the following:

- add a GlobalWindow with triggers instead of fixed windows:

  ```
      .apply("globalwindow", Window.<MutationGroup>into(new GlobalWindows())
              .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
                      .pastFirstElementInPane()
                      .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
              ).orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
              .discardingFiredPanes()
              .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO))
  ```

  This results in writes to spanner only when I drain my pipeline. I have the impression the `Wait.on()` signal is only triggered when the Global windows closes, and doesn't work with triggers.
- Disable the `.apply(Wait.on(input))` in SpannerIO:

  This results in the pipeline getting stuck on the view creation which
  is described in this SO post:
  [SpannerIO Dataflow 2.3.0 stuck in CreateDataflowView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273528/spannerio-dataflow-2-3-0-stuck-in-createdataflowview).

  When I check the worker logs for clues, I do get the following warnings:

  ```
  logger:  "org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder"
  message:  "Can't verify serialized elements of type SpannerSchema have well defined equals method. This may produce incorrect results on some PipelineRunner
  logger:  "org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder"   
  message:  "Can't verify serialized elements of type BoundedSource have well defined equals method. This may produce incorrect results on some PipelineRunner"
  ```

Note that everything works with the DirectRunner and that I'm trying to use the DataflowRunner.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for things I can try to get this running? I can hardly imagine that I'm the only one trying to stream MutationGroups into spanner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, SpannerIO connector is not supported with Beam Streaming. Please follow [this Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6478) which adds streaming support for spanner IO connector.